# printing multi-line strings

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying a log per line for a multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669590/displaying-a-log-per-line-for-a-multiline-text)

Given `String m = "abc\ncdf";` and using slf4j with log4j,

If I try to `logger.debug(m);` that string inside of `SomeClass.doSomething()` method, the text after new line will be displayed without the standard logging prefix:

```
10:40:35,732 [DEBUG] SomeClass.doSomething():32: abc
cdf
```

If I use a util method to split the string and print each line as its own logger call:

```
class PrintUtil {
    public static void print(String s) {
        for(String line : s.split("\\n"))
            logger.debug(line);
    }
}
```

and change `SomeClass.doSomething()` to call `PrintUtil.print(m);` then I lose the original class information:

```
10:40:35,737 [DEBUG] PrintUtil.print():45: abc
10:40:35,737 [DEBUG] PrintUtil.print():45: cdf
```

Is it possible to print multi line strings without losing the calling class/method information?

To clarify, the desired output would be:

```
10:40:35,732 [DEBUG] SomeClass.doSomething():32: abc
10:40:35,732 [DEBUG] SomeClass.doSomething():32: cdf
```

Answer (score 0):

if i under stood you right you want some thing like that:

```
 10:40:35,737 [DEBUG] PrintUtil.print():45: abc
                                            cdf
```

what about adding '\t' (tab) to the string?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the output I'm trying to create

Comment: you could add the data you want in the function. you should be able to check the stack and find out who invoked the function PrintUtil.print(). fast googling give me that: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t67019.html . not so handsome, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add "\r\n"

```
logger.info("test\r\ntest");
```