# Implement User Log in a Centralized Way

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on finding a way to Log UserActions/Requests. I'm inclined towards logging the details to a text file. The LOG details are organized in a tree-like (hierarchical) structure so that it is readable and shows method names in a step-by-step manner. (if a request went through several methods)

I have a sample app which works fine but it is not the way how it should be. Consider the following classes.

**Node** class which is the template to make a tree-like (hierarchical) structure. It has attributes such as name (method name), Time and a List type para named Children.

```
public class Node
    {
        public string Name; // method name
        public DateTime Time; // time when accessed
        public List<Node> Children;

        public static void PrintTree(Node tree)
        {
            string temp  = "";
            List<Node> firstStack = new List<Node>();
            firstStack.Add(tree);

            List<List<Node>> childListStack = new List<List<Node>>();
            childListStack.Add(firstStack);

            while (childListStack.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Node> childStack = childListStack[childListStack.Count - 1];

                if (childStack.Count == 0)
                {
                    childListStack.RemoveAt(childListStack.Count - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    tree = childStack[0];
                    childStack.RemoveAt(0);

                    string indent = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < childListStack.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        indent += (childListStack[i].Count > 0) ? "|  " : "   ";
                    }

                    temp = indent + "+- " + tree.Name + " (" + tree.Time + ")";
                    Console.WriteLine(indent + "+- " + tree.Name + " (" + tree.Time + ")");

                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\aimalkhan\Desktop\Log Work\Log.txt", temp + Environment.NewLine);

                    if (tree.Children != null)
                    {
                        if (tree.Children.Count > 0)
                        {
                            childListStack.Add(new List<Node>(tree.Children));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\aimalkhan\Desktop\Log Work\Log.txt", Environment.NewLine + "*************************************************************" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

My sample **Employee** class with a sample method **SetEmployeeName()** having **AN EXTRA** parameter of **NODE type** for Logging purposes.

```
public class Employee
    {
        private string FirstName { get; set; }
        private string LastName { get; set; }

        public string SetEmployeeName(string firstName, string lastName, Node node)
        {
            node.Name = "Class Name: " +this.GetType().Name + ", Calling method Name: setEmployeeName()";
            node.Time = DateTime.Now;

            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;

            return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
        }

        public void CompleteTask(string empName, string taskName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee: " + empName + " is completing the task: " + taskName);
        }
    }
```

and finally this is how i'm using the aforementioned sample of Codes.

```
Node root = new Node();
            root.Name = "ClassName: Main";
            root.Time = DateTime.Now;

            root.Children = new List<Node>();
            Node child = new Node();

            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.SetEmployeeName("John", "D", child);

            root.Children.Add(child);

            Node.PrintTree(root);
```

This is how the output looks[image]

Now my question is that it would really be a headache for me to pass a NODE type para every time i need a child info log. Could this be some how made centralized in any possible way? Is there a better way than this one? A little guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: What about using a logging framework that supports indented log entries?

Comment: @peterBons Sure, could you name a few?

Comment: Check out http://www.dotnetlogging.com/

Comment: @JacobKrall Thank you for the suggestion. The article has various options but do any of them supports indented log entries as PeterBons pointed out?!

Comment: Log4net seems to provide extensions to do it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927351/how-to-add-indentation-to-multi-line-log-entry-in-log4net. As does NLog, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951102/nlog-custom-layoutrenderer.  Maybe more.

Comment: Sure i'll check these out, but do they link request calls to each other as if to know which entry to indent? @peterbons i'm just curious.

Comment: It seems the second link from my comments does do something like that yes, but to be honest, I do not know exactly

Comment: @peterBons i checked the provided links and unfortunately they do not solve my issue. They just log the events/requests, both of them either NLog or log4net.